# Turn on tv using cec-client on RPi3

Tags: pi-3b+, cec-client

Running latest Libreelec with latest Kodi on RPi3.

I can successfully turn off the tv using:

```
echo "standby 0" | cec-client RPI -s -d 1
```

and

```
echo "tx 10:36" | cec-client RPI -s -d 4
```

But turning the tv on is not possible. I don't know if it's my Sony Bravia.

I'm executing `echo "tx 10:04" | cec-client RPI -s -d 4` and `echo "on 0" | cec-client RPI -s -d 1`, neither of which work.

Hoping someone can shed some light on this. I do see this in the log after running the 'on' command:

> marking opcode 'image view on' as unsupported feature for device 'TV'

Just want to know if there is a workaround or there is no chance of it working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that wouldn't work; Both of your commands are correctly formatted. I don't think it's because your TV is Sony, though ([source](http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/Vendor/Support)), but it may be that your TV doesn't support CEC when it's in standby (I think that's against the specs, so I'm not sure).

Since you see that error:

1. Your TV sent back a "Feature Abort" meaning that it got the command, but doesn't support it.
2. Maybe you never got a response from the TV at all, which would make me think that the TV was fully powered off or doesn't support CEC in standby, which seems counter-intuitive.

Posting the full output (leave off `-d 1`) may help get to the bottom of it.

If you are feeling up to digging through the HDMI CEC Specs, I found them [here](http://bfiles.chinaaet.com/whpt/blog/20170919/1000008562-6364143185282736974850538.pdf#page=213).